# How to sort report layout with vba code

Tags: vba, ms-access, layout, report, ms-access-2007

I wish to create a report like the excel template below

[image: Excel]

Here is my table where all the records are stored

[image]

Here is a quick and rough solution of the report.

[image]

My question is if I change the hours column to Monday through to Sunday columns, where would I put the vb code to do a check on the Breakdown.Day column to insert the value into the right day ?

Would the above approach be suitable for what I am trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a crosstab query and then build a report based on that.

Start by experimenting with `Query Wizard > Crosstab Query Wizard` to discover how you can group various fields (up to 3 of them) as Row Headings -- e.g., [Code], [Description], [Customer] -- and then specify [Day] as the Column Headings. Sum the [Hours] as the crosstab "Values" and then take a look at the query result. It won't look *exactly* like the Excel template (e.g., the days will probably be sorted alphabetically), but it should at least give you the raw data you need to populate your report.